# C#: Regex Replace Matches after Conversion

Tags: c#, regex

Right now, I am working on a RPN calculator with Winforms (C#). I am able to store fractions like "1/2" for example in a label. So when my label contains several fractions, I want to convert them first into decimal numbers, so that they will be put on my stack. Below you can find my method how I want to do it. However, when I have for example "1/2" and "6/3" in my label, for both values I get "2" and "2" instead of "0.5" and "2".

Any ideas how to solve this?
Many thanks in advance!

```
private void SearchforFrac()
{
    string pattern = @"(\d+)(/)(\d+)";
    decimal new1 = 0;
    int numerator = 0;
    int denominator = 1;

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(labelCurrentOperation.Text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        numerator = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        denominator = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
    }
    new1 = (decimal)numerator / (decimal)denominator;
    String res = Convert.ToString(new1);

    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    labelCurrentOperation.Text = rgx.Replace(labelCurrentOperation.Text, res);        
}
```

Comment: You need to do more inside the `foreach` loop. If you just set the numerator and denominator then after the loop you just get the last value of both of those (i.e. your 6/3 = 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
public static string ReplaceFraction(string inputString)
{
    string pattern = @"(\d+)(/)(\d+)";
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputString, pattern, (match) =>
    {
        decimal numerator = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        decimal denominator = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
        return (numerator / denominator).ToString();
    });
}
```

Example:

```
string Result = ReplaceFraction("sometext 9/3 sometext 4/2 sometext");
```

Result:

```
"sometext 3 sometext 2 sometext"
```

**EDIT**

if you couldn't use code above, try this:

```
private void SearchforFrac()
{
    string pattern = @"(\d+)(/)(\d+)";
    labelCurrentOperation.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(labelCurrentOperation.Text, pattern,delegate (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match)
    {
        decimal numerator = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        decimal denominator = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
        return (numerator / denominator).ToString();
    });
}
```

**OR**

```
private void SearchforFrac()
{
    string pattern = @"(\d+)(/)(\d+)";
    this.labelCurrentOperation.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(this.labelCurrentOperation.Text, pattern, evaluator);
}
private string evaluator(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match)
{
    decimal numerator = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    decimal denominator = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
    return (numerator / denominator).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man, I will try this!

Comment: Hello Hussein, I am not sure if this will work. My input string comes from a label, Form1.LabelCurrentOperation.Text, which is actually a non-static property

Comment: Hi,  use Form1.LabelCurrentOperation.Text=ReplaceFraction(Form1.LabelCurrentOperation.Text); you can also remove static keyword.

Comment: Hi, I tried it like  public string Form1.LabelCurrentOperation.Text=ReplaceFraction(Form1.Label‌​CurrentOperation.Tex‌​t);
        {
            string pattern = @"(\d+)(/)(\d+)";
            return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputString, pattern, (match) =>
            {
                decimal numerator = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
                decimal denominator = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
                return (numerator / denominator).ToString();
            });
        }

Comment: Unfortunately this is producing more errors. Even if I try to correct them, one stays, CS7036... I don´t know

Comment: I thought "Form1" is object name not a class Name! for example you can use:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.LabelCurrentOperation.Text = ReplaceFraction(this.Label‌CurrentOperation.Tex‌t);
}

Comment: Please try edited answer. Which version of C# you are using and what is your tool (Visual Studio, Xamarin, Mono, ...)?

Comment: Hi Hussein, I tried both of your second proposals and they are working both! Thanks a lot Man, I really appreciate this !! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!